# Is there a reason java restricts the instantiation of parameterized array types to a single fashion?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, type-systems

Java allows raw array types to instantiate in these two fashions

```
ArrayList [] aList = new ArrayList[1];
// or
ArrayList [] aList = {new ArrayList()};
```

But parameterized array types are only allowed to instantiate in this fashion:

```
ArrayList<String> [] aList = new ArrayList[1];
```

While the other fashion will cause a compile time error. Why is this?

Comment: I think you mean ArrayList<String>[] aList = new ArrayList[1]; this?

Comment: Absolutely did, good catch

Comment: ArrayList<String> [] aList = new ArrayList<>[1];

Answer (score 0):

Someone else answered that when you instantiate an array with the inline syntax:

`ArrayList<String> [] aList = {new ArrayList()};`

"the type system uses the static type to create the array which in this case is a non-reified type so java forbids it" To which I asked what he meant about static types; in his reply he referred me to [section 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-10.html) of the JLS saying that with the above syntax `ArrayList<String>[]` is the component type; I replied that I think `ArrayList<String>[]` is the component type of `ArrayList<String> [] aList = new ArrayList[1]` as well so it doesn't make sense to me why java allows one but not the other. Then he deleted his answer entirely.

So I'm not sure if I caught a flaw in his answer or if he just got tired of me asking questions, but if anyone knows this is true please confirm it.

Comment: But there you don't use array initializers, instead array is created by an array creation expression. The problem occurs when you use array initializers. Static type refers to the compile time type.

Comment: I understood that part and that makes sense. What threw me off is when you said `ArrayList<String>[]` is the component type when I use array initializers but not creation expressions. Wouldn't `ArrayList<String>[]` be the component type for both fashions?

Comment: The component type is `ArrayList<String>` when you array initializers and the raw type `ArrayList` when you create the array. That difference causes the problem.

Comment: The component type is `ArrayList<String>` when you use array initializers and the raw type `ArrayList` when you create the array. That difference causes the problem. If you declare the static type as the raw type, then there's no problem.

Comment: Ok I'm sure you're right so thanks for clearing that up, I'm going to try to find the section of the JLS that explains that just because I want to get more familiar with the JLS. I didn't see anything in the link you shared that explained the different component types for different syntax of instantiation

Comment: Nevermind, the link you shared did explain this, I just missed it

Comment: If you are interested in learning generics more, I would recommend you reading this book. https://www.amazon.com/Java-Generics-Collections-Development-Process/dp/0596527756

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! Will check it out.